# cURL Option - session and cookie

Tags: php, curl, cookies

In a script I used cURL for login or post some information to another site.

When a user loads this script we have not any problem but when two user simultaneously load script the another site loads first page, because the cookie in our host set for one user, and the site get two different commands from a user.

How can I do that when the script was loaded for any user that the site get different SESSION and COOKIE to each user?

```
$ch = curl_init();
$agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
return $result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have user id for each user you can do something like

fill in $user_id with id from user table and then

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie'.$user_id.'.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie'.$user_id.'.txt');
```